# Controller not being found

Tags: angularjs

I'm just now giving angular a try. I'm defining a controller in a CustomersController.js. But, when I run I get an error "Error: error:areq Bad Argument". My CustomersController is not being found.  Any would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,600,700,800,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body ng-controller="CustomersController">

    <h2>Customers</h2>
    Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name" />

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="doSort('name')">Name</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('city')">City</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('orderTotal')">Order Total</th>
            <th ng-click="doSort('joined')">Joined</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:customerFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
            <td>{{ cust.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ cust.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ cust.orderTotal | currency }}</td>
            <td>{{ cust.joined | date }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/customersController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CustomerController.js

```
function CustomersController($scope){
    $scope.sortBy = 'name';
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.customers = [
        {
            joined: "2000-12-24", 
            name: "Charles", 
            city: "Fairfax", 
            orderTotal: "12414432.45"
        },
        {
            joined: "2000-09-12", 
            name: "Jack", 
            city: "Altamonte Springs", 
            orderTotal: "5.9943"
        },
        {
            joined: "2000-01-25", 
            name: "Bill", 
            city: "Waldorf", 
            orderTotal: "100"
        }
    ],
    $scope.doSort = function(propName){
        $scope.sortBy = propName;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this line to your CustomerController.js

```
 angular.module("app", []).controller("CustomersController", CustomersController);
```

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("CustomersController", CustomersController);



function CustomersController($scope) {
  $scope.sortBy = 'name';
  $scope.reverse = false;
  $scope.customers = [{
      joined: "2000-12-24",
      name: "Charles",
      city: "Fairfax",
      orderTotal: "12414432.45"
    }, {
      joined: "2000-09-12",
      name: "Jack",
      city: "Altamonte Springs",
      orderTotal: "5.9943"
    }, {
      joined: "2000-01-25",
      name: "Bill",
      city: "Waldorf",
      orderTotal: "100"
    }],
    $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
      $scope.sortBy = propName;
      $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,600,700,800,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body ng-controller="CustomersController">

  <h2>Customers</h2>
  Filter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name" />

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th ng-click="doSort('name')">Name</th>
      <th ng-click="doSort('city')">City</th>
      <th ng-click="doSort('orderTotal')">Order Total</th>
      <th ng-click="doSort('joined')">Joined</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:customerFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
      <td>{{ cust.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ cust.city }}</td>
      <td>{{ cust.orderTotal | currency }}</td>
      <td>{{ cust.joined | date }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app/controllers/customersController.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you sss. I've been looking at this for about 2 hours now

Answer (score 0):

Controllers, services, directives and filters should all be contained within an Angular module. There are two primary methods of defining the controller for a page. Either using [routing](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) or simply with [`ngController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController). You're attempting to use `ngController` but have not defined the module.

Within you HTML you can define your main module with [`ngApp`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp).

So your HTML tag could read:

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">
```

Then you can assign your existing `CustomersController` to this module with:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('CustomersController', CustomersController);
```

Alternatively, another approach is to simply define the controller logic in a controller block with:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller(function() {
    // your logic here
  });
```